# Extending Vuetify's VBtn component to create a reusable icon button component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, extend

I've been using the example Codepen (https://codepen.io/whoistobias/pen/yLNgjwy) to try to extend the Vuetify `VBtn` component to create a reusable Button Icon component.

I'm awfully close, but as usual I'm stumbling at the last hurdle.

The main code is this:

```js
const VBtn = Vue.options.components["VBtn"];
const VIcon = Vue.options.components["VIcon"];

const ButtonIcon = {
  name: 'ButtonIcon',
  
  extends: VBtn,

  props: {
    icon: {
      default: true,
      type: Boolean
    },
    iconColor: {
      default: 'info',
      type: String
    },
    iconName: {
      default: 'help',
      type: String
    },
    outline: {
      default: true,
      type: Boolean
    }
  },

  methods: {
    genContent () {
      return this.$createElement('div', {
        class: 'v-btn__content'
      }, this.$slots.default || [this.$createElement(
        VIcon,
        {
          props: {
            color: this.iconColor
          }
        },
        this.iconName
      )])
    }
  }
};
```

The bit that's not quite right is where the `this.iconName` is being inserted into the `VIcon`. The output of this is `"add"` instead of `add` when the prop `iconName`'s value is `add`.

I've done my best to try digest the contents of the help docs around using `createElement` in the Vue docs - https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html?redirect=true#createElement-Arguments

Here's my forked Codepen of the working code: https://codepen.io/scp-nm/pen/PoQPVEP

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your icon names are incorrect. The default icon names are prefixed with `mdi-`. You can see the list of available icons from https://materialdesignicons.com/.

I'm assuming `mdi-plus` is a good icon for "add", and `mdi-help-circle-outline` for "help":

```html
                                               
<ButtonIcon icon-color="success" icon-name="mdi-plus" title="Icon Button (custom prop values)" />
```

```js
const ButtonIcon = {
  ⋮
  props: {
    iconName: {   
      default: 'mdi-help-circle-outline',
      type: String
    },
  },
}
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/eYVJybd?editors=1010)

Comment: D-oh! Thanks, you're absolutely correct.